# How do i constrain an image to a maximum width/height?

Tags: jquery

Right now I'm trying the following code. This works most of the time (on a reload, after the 1st visit) but when visiting the page the first time, the image isn't resized properly. 
I *think* this is because because the image is loaded before the page ready callback is triggered.

I've tried calling the `.resize()` function directly in the `.ready()` callback but the image still don't resize on occasion because the image may bot be loaded when the `.ready()` callback is triggered.

How should i go about hooking up the `resize()` function to get the images to resize properly regardless when the load?

```
function resize($img) {
    var max_size_w = 200;
    var max_size_h = 200;
    var h = $img.height();
    var w = $img.width();
    if (h > max_size_h) {
        h = max_size_h;
        w = Math.ceil($img.width() / $img.height() * max_size_h);
    }
    if (w > max_size_w) {
        h = Math.ceil($img.height() / $img.width() * max_size_w);
        w = max_size_w;
    }
    $img.css({ height: h, width: w });
}

$().ready(function() {
    // Size the images correctly
    $(".personPictureImage").each(function() {
        $(this).find("img").load(function() { resize($(this)); });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** The HTML

```
<div class="personPicture">
    <div class="personPictureFrame">
        <div class="personPictureImage">
            <a href="../images/media/popup/46.png" class="lightbox">
                <img src="../images/media/thumbnail/46.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="personPictureFrameTL"></div>
        <div class="personPictureFrameTR"></div>
        <div class="personPictureFrameBL"></div>
        <div class="personPictureFrameBR"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us the structure of your HTML? what is the `.personPictureImage`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using CSS for this? - .personPictureImage img { max-width:200px; max-height:200px; }

Comment: @udjamaflip - That doesn't work in most IE version

Comment: Did you try calling the resize function on `$(window).load(function(){ ... });`?

Comment: @fudgey - no but adding it to both load and ready fixed the issue. write up an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a call to the function inside of a window load function to resize after all of the images have loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Size the images correctly
    $(".personPictureImage").each(function() {
        resize($(this));
    });
});
```

Also using `$().ready` has been deprecated, use `$(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - well I guess it's "to be" deprecated... it does say not recommended to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function resize($img) {
    var max_size_w = 200;
    var max_size_h = 200;
    var h = $img.height();
    var w = $img.width();
    if (h > max_size_h) {
        h = max_size_h;
        w = Math.ceil($img.width() / $img.height() * max_size_h);
    }
    if (w > max_size_w) {
        h = Math.ceil($img.height() / $img.width() * max_size_w);
        w = max_size_w;
    }
    $img.css({ height: h, width: w });
    }

    $(".personPictureImage").each(function() {
        $(this).find("img").load(function() { resize($(this)); });
    });

}())
```

That should work.

Comment: This looks to just move the resize function into the ready callback. How does that solve the timing issue (ie, the image was loaded before the ready callback was called)?